# Can I add speed to this jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Firstly could you view my outcome http://jsfiddle.net/RXnKR/

From this I decided as you click the more button I'd like it to animate slowly and was unsure whether I could alter this to make that happen? I am happy for any kind of recommendation and would really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another soloution, which seems more smooth;
http://jsfiddle.net/RXnKR/6/

```
    $('.more').each(function () {
        var content = $(this).html();
        var height = $(this).height();
        $(this).data('fullheight', height);

        if (content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar - 1, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsesText + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
            $(this).html(html);
            var collapsedHeight = $(this).height();
            $(this).data('smallheight', collapsedHeight);
        }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function () {

        var parentMore = $(this).parents('.more');
        var more = $(this);

        if (more.hasClass("less")) {
              parentMore.animate({
                  height: parentMore.data('smallheight')
              }, 1000, function() {
                more.removeClass("less");
                more.html(moretext);
              });

        } else {
              parentMore.animate({
                  height: parentMore.data('fullheight')
              }, 1000, function() {
                more.addClass("less");
                more.html(lesstext);
              });

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/RXnKR/5/

Keep in mind that in this case ".morecontent span" must have persistent height, otherwise on the next run if height was changed, then part of the text could overflow other elements or there could be extra whitespace. So if height changes you have to recalculate it.

That's not a question, though, and you're receiving downvotes quite fairly. I'd consult [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) before posting next time.